# Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2). at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hey Ive trouble shooted over many pages but nothing solves this!!
please help!

i went through so many solutions, but nothing works!

I tried going over many other stack overflow pages, but none of them work: heres the main error:

Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).

```
package form;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import database.DB_Connection;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class report
 */
@WebServlet("/report")
public class report extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */


    public static String makeDate(String dateString) {
        //2019-09-20 10:01:02
        String date = dateString;
        String finalString;

        String[] arrOfStr = date.split("T"); 
        finalString = arrOfStr[0] + " " + arrOfStr[1] + ":00";

        System.err.println("I am the final string" + finalString);

        return finalString;

    }

    public static String makeint(String timeString) {
        //2019-09-20 10:01:02
        String date = timeString;
        String finalString;

        String[] arrOfStr = date.split(" "); 
        finalString = arrOfStr[0];

        System.err.println("I am the final string" + finalString);

        return finalString;

    }
    public report() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String elements[] = new String[10];

        elements[0] = request.getParameter("reportDescription");
        elements[1] = request.getParameter("recording");
        elements[2] = request.getParameter("Incident");
        elements[3] = request.getParameter("date");
        elements[4] = request.getParameter("accident");
        elements[5] = request.getParameter("address");
        elements[6] = request.getParameter("sendEmail");


        DB_Connection obj_DB_Connection = new DB_Connection();
        Connection connection = obj_DB_Connection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            String query = ("INSERT INTO `Hiho`.`IncidentReports`\n" + 
                    "(\n" + 
                    "`Description`,\n" + 
                    "`RecordingTime`,\n" + 
                    "`IncidentType`,\n" + 
                    "`ReportDate`,\n" + 
                    "`AccidentType`,\n" + 
                    "`Location`,\n" + 
                    "`Email`)\n" + 
                    "VALUES\n" + 
                    "( '?',\n" + 
                    "?,\n" + 
                    "'?', \n" + 
                    "'?',\n" + 
                    "'?',\n" + 
                    "'?',\n" + 
                    "?\n" + 
                    ");\n" + 
                    "");

            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);


//          for (int i = 0; i < elements[1].length(); i++) {
//              if (Character.isDigit(elements[1].charAt(i))) {
//                  continue;
//              }
//              
//          }



            int timeAmount= Integer.parseInt(makeint(elements[1]) );


            elements[3] = makeDate(elements[3]);




            System.out.println(timeAmount);
            System.out.println(elements[3]);
            System.out.println(elements);

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i]== null) {
                    break;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {  
                    System.out.println("I just printed it up!!!");
                    ps.setInt(i+1, timeAmount);

                }
                else if (i==6) {

                    if (elements[i] == "1") {
                        System.out.println(elements[i]);
                        ps.setBoolean(i+1, true);
                    }

                    else {

                        System.out.println(elements[i]);
                        ps.setBoolean(i+1, false);
                    }

                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("I am here for: " + elements[i] + "and my index is: " );
                    System.out.println(i);
                    ps.setString(i+1, elements[i] );
                }

            }

            ps.executeUpdate();

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            System.out.println(ps);
            System.out.println(rs);



        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if(connection!=null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i]== null)
                break;
            System.out.println(elements[i].getClass().getName() + " " + elements[i]);
        }




        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Hey Ive trouble shooted over many pages but nothing solves this!! please help!

i went through so many solutions, but nothing works!

I tried going over many other stack overflow pages, but none of them work: heres the main error:

Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).

Comment: Don't put `?` JDBC parameter markers inside `'` single-quotes. `'?'` is a SQL text literal of length 1 with a single-quote character. `?` is a JDBC parameter marker. You're even **mixing** `'?'` and `?` in the same SQL string. Why on earth would you do that and think the difference wouldn't matter? --- If you think you need `'?'` to tell JDBC that the value is a string, re-think that. JDBC will know because you'd be setting the value using `setString(...)`. The marker is still just a `?`.

Comment: and get rid of the `\n`

Comment: What is `ps.executeUpdate(); rs = ps.executeQuery();` supposed to do? Why are you trying to run the **same SQL** as both an update statement and a query? Since it's an `INSERT`, use `executeUpdate()` and get rid of `executeQuery()`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat That doesn't actually hurt any, and may make the SQL look pretty if you display it, e.g. in a log message or with a tool monitoring the database.

Answer (score 1):

As @andreas mentioned, change query as below:

```
            String query = ("INSERT INTO `Hiho`.`IncidentReports`\n" + 
                    "(\n" + 
                    "`Description`,\n" + 
                    "`RecordingTime`,\n" + 
                    "`IncidentType`,\n" + 
                    "`ReportDate`,\n" + 
                    "`AccidentType`,\n" + 
                    "`Location`,\n" + 
                    "`Email`)\n" + 
                    "VALUES\n" + 
                    "( ?,\n" + 
                    "?,\n" + 
                    "?, \n" + 
                    "?,\n" + 
                    "?,\n" + 
                    "?,\n" + 
                    "?\n" + 
                    ");\n" + 
                    "");
```

Also, not sure why are you defining elements length as 10, setting only 7 values but iterating through all elements as checking for null. Why don't you define array length as 7 instead?